# Android pay , samsung pay on website using php

Tags: php, android, stripe-payments, samsung-pay

I have a e commerce website where i want to add SAMSUNG PAY and ANDROID PAY
when website accessed from mobile.

Is there any API / SDK available for PHP ?
For example we have everything required to implement for APPLE PAY in stripe as describe in https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web

How can i implement it using PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: stripe has a php api

Comment: can you send me a link for same ?

Comment: http://adyen.github.io/adyen-php-api-library/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the payment gateway you want to work with. Most of the time you just need to pass the walled payload to the payment gateway, such as Strip or Adyen.

In order to integrate with Samsung Pay, you have to check the country and payment gateway you are working with:

Access https://pay.samsung.com/partners/ and contact a Samsung Pay Relationship Manager

Here is the portal for developers: https://pay.samsung.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

You can find Stripe's PHP library here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

Answer (score 0):

You can find Adyen PHP SDK quick start on this page: http://adyen.github.io/adyen-php-api-library/